# My bundle is saved but is always null I believe. It never calls the I want to resume my app nicely. Please help

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here is some of my code in my activity. Please help.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   <MISC SETUP CODE>

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        // we were just launched: set up a new game
        mLunarView.setState(GameView.STATE_READY);
        Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "SIS is null");
    } else {
        // we are being restored: resume a previous game
        mLunarThread.restoreState(savedInstanceState);
        mLunarView.mGameScore = savedInstanceState.getInt("GAMESCORE");
        Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "SIS is nonnull");
    }

    context = this;
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // just have the View's thread save its state into our Bundle
    //outState = mLunarThread.saveState(outState);
    outState.putInt("GAMESCORE", 456);
    Log.w(this.getClass().getName(), "SIS Saved");


}
```

Comment: I made a bundle for my main activity and a bool to tell if it was loaded. it it was it didn't create a new thread / gameview /etc. i used the pause / resume functions

Answer (score 0):

should there be a onResume somewhere that would restore the saved state?

Comment: I thought about this as well but how do you get the created bundle into this function????

Answer (score 0):

Try changing :

```
if (savedInstanceState == null)
```

to:

```
if (!savedInstanceState.containsKey("GAMESCORE")
```

Comment: this crashes the program. im not sure why.

Comment: because savedInstanceState is null. Your original code was correct. Just need to check the key in the 'else' loop.

Answer (score 0):

How was your activity destroyed? Did you press 'Back' button, or have another activity come on top of it?

1) If you press 'Back', then there won't be any bundle saved, because the activity is destroyed totally.

2) If another activity come on top of it (incoming call, SMS, or you launch another activity), then it depends on the available memory of your phone at that instant. If you have enough memory, then onCreate will not be called upon returning to this activity. If you have low memory, then onCreate will be called with the bundle saved before another activity appeared on top of yours.

Therefore, if your plan is to restore activity state for case (1), then you need to save the state yourself, into SharedPreference, or sqliteDb.

Comment: Pressed Home then reopened icon.

Comment: Try this: if you are testing on emulator, launch the app 'Dev Tools', in 'Development Settings', check the box 'Immediately destroy activities'. Then from your app, press home and click on its icon again. In my case, the activity is resumed and the bundle is passed in.

Comment: how would i save the state myself?

Comment: this made it get the bundle i believe in oncreate. "Try this: if you are testing on emulator, launch the app 'Dev Tools', in 'Development Settings', check the box 'Immediately destroy activities'." Will this be the same behavior on phone or what doe shte immediately destroy activities try to replicate

Comment: on a phone you will have different possibilities depending on the memory state. But really, your code was correct, you properly restore the state on onCreate. If onCreate is not called at all, then onResume will be called, and you don't need to restore anything as the activity should retain its states. If onCreate is called with null bundle, then the OS is telling you to launch the activity with new states. If onCreate is called with a bundle, then you just restore the states.

Comment: onSavedInstanceState() isn't always called - check http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29 for more details

Comment: this 'fix' while works on the emulator doesn't restore the data on my phone.